# Topological superconductor definitions

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, topological-insulators

Topological insulators are materials who are conductors on the boudary  but not in the bulk. What is the definition of tolopological superconductor? A superconductor on the boundary but not in the bulk?

Comment: You may have a look at [arXiv 1608.03395](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03395).